# Rx timer state not updating in view in Cycle.js

Tags: javascript, rxjs, virtual-dom, cyclejs, hyperscript

I'm starting a timer when someone clicks a button that I intend to use as the opacity for some element. When I use `do` to trace the value I can see it spitting out to the console 40 times, but in the view the number stays put. Not sure where I'm going wrong here:

```
let intent = ({ DOM }) => ({
  clickLogin$: DOM.select('.sign-in').events('click').map(ev => true)
})

let model = ({ clickLogin$ }) =>
  Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    clickLogin$.startWith(false),
    clickLogin$.map(x =>
      Rx.Observable.timer(1, 1)
    ).switch().startWith(0).take(40),
    (signingIn, fadeValue) => ({ signingIn, fadeValue })
  )

let view = (state$) => {
  return state$.do(
    x => console.log(x.fadeValue)) // this fires |--1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-->
  .map(({ signingIn, fadeValue }) =>
    div(`.app`, [
      div([fadeValue]), // this value does not change
      If(signingIn,
        div(`.overlay`, {
          style: {
            backgroundColor: `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.${fadeValue})` // nor does this
          }  
        })
      )
    ])
  )  
}

let main = (sources) => {
  let view$ = view(model(intent(sources)))
  return {
    DOM: view$,
    history: sources.History,
    Props: sources.Props,
  }
}
```

UPDATE: Turns out having a small error in hyperscript caused it strange behaviour. I didn't even include it in my example because I didn't think it was relevant.

```
div(`content`, [ `testing` ])
```

Simply changing the above to (adding indication of class)

```
div(`.content`, [ `testing` ])
```

Caused everything to magically work.

Comment: `If(signingIn,` what is the `If` function?

Comment: Also, you might want to append a `repeat` at the end of `clickLogin$.map(x =>
      Rx.Observable.timer(1, 1)
    ).switch().startWith(0).take(40)`, because after 40 clicks, the observable will complete and you will receive no more value from it.

Comment: `If` such a simple helper function: `let If = (c, e) => c ? e : null` but you're right.. removing it works.. why??

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a full answer, but it helps identifying the problem. I removed the `If` part of the view code generation, and added `repeat`, put that in [tricycle](http://widdersh.in/tricycle/) and you can see that the `fadeValue` is generated sequentially as expected.

```
var Cycle = require('@cycle/core');
var CycleDOM = require('@cycle/dom');
var Rx = require('rx');
var makeDOMDriver = CycleDOM.makeDOMDriver;
var div = CycleDOM.div;

var sources = {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('.app')
};

let main = (sources) => {

let intent = ({ DOM }) => ({
  clickLogin$: Rx.Observable.interval(3000).take(5).share()
})

let model = ({ clickLogin$ }) =>
  Rx.Observable.combineLatest(
    clickLogin$.startWith(false),
    clickLogin$.flatMapLatest(function (x) {
      return Rx.Observable.timer(200, 200);
    }).take(10).repeat(),
    (signingIn, fadeValue) => ({ signingIn, fadeValue })
  )

let view = (state$) => {
  return state$.do(
    x => console.log(x.fadeValue)) // this fires |--1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-->
  .map(({ signingIn, fadeValue }) =>
    div(`.app`, [
      div([fadeValue]) // this value does not change
    ])
  )  
}

  let view$ = view(model(intent(sources)))
  return {
    DOM: view$,
    history: sources.History,
    Props: sources.Props,
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! You helped me find the answer indeed.... it was because I was missing a `.` in a hyperscript tag.. `div('content', ['testing'])`. content without the class indicator made everything blow up silently.

Comment: thanks @azium! no thanks, surprising silent failure in @cycle/dom (or virtual-hyperscript)! ugh